# Know installation source of PHP

Tags: homebrew, macports, macos, php

I'm finding myself in an awkward situation. I need to install PHP and Nginx for development but I do not want to mess up my Mac with multiple installations. I have found that PHP and PHP-fpm are already installed. I would like to uninstall but I have no clue on how to do it as I don't know through what means it has been installed (Brew or Ports).

I have searched the php binary and it is in `/usr/bin/`

```
PHP 5.5.30 (cli) (built: Oct 23 2015 17:21:45) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies

Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.3
```

Comment: Anything in /usr/bin is installed via Apple and should not be touched. However if you have both macports and homebrew and you asking this sort of question you will have problems I would reinstall OS X from scratch and choose only one package manager

Comment: `php` is included with OS X. Please can you add the output of `/usr/bin/php --version` and the version of OS X you are using.

Answer (score 1):

`PHP 5.5.30 (cli) (built: Oct 23 2015 17:21:45)` is the version of `php` shipped by Apple with OS X 10.11.3.

You can use [brew](http://brew.sh) to install a current version of `php` – without affecting the built-in version.

`brew` installs its binaries in `/usr/local/Cellar`. A modification to your `PATH` ensures the brew installed version is found before the OS X provided version.

[MacPorts](https://www.macports.org) uses a similar approach. Which package provider you use is a matter of personal preference.

### Install php via brew

To install `php` via `brew`, first install `brew` using [the instructions on their web site](http://brew.sh):

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then install `php`:

```
brew install php
```

### Remove php via brew

When you need to remove `php` installed via `brew` – thus reverting `php` back to the version shipped with OS X – run:

```
brew uninstall php
```